# AttributeError: 'logfileOpen' object has no attribute 'dataList'

Tags: python, class, attributes

When I try to access the attributes of a particular class that I have defined, I get an error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:/PythonCodes/#####/####.py", line 73, in <module>  
  print(ReadinOut.dataList)
AttributeError: 'logfileOpen' object has no attribute 'dataList'
```

I am just getting started trying to use tkinter to make a GUI in Python. The error occurs whenever I try to access the attributes of the class, e.g. if I type `Object.Attribute`.

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()


class logfileOpen(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def fileOpen(self):
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select file", filetypes=(("xvi log files", "*.log"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        self.Filename = filename
        # print (filename)

    def readlogFile(self):
        with open(self.Filename, 'r') as a:  # Reading in from the file.
            for line in a:
                typeofevent = line.split(' ')
                if len(line) > 2:
                    if typeofevent[3] == "[Error]":
                        print(line)
        a.close()

    def storeEvents(self):
        datalist = []
        with open(self.Filename, 'r') as b:  # Reading in from the file.
            for line in b:
                typeofevent = line.split(' ')
                if len(line) > 2:
                    datalist.append(typeofevent)
        b.close()
        self.dataList = datalist

    def openfileroutine(self):
        self.fileOpen()
        self.storeEvents


class GraphicsStuff:
    def __init__(self, graphichandle):
        self.graphicHandle = graphichandle

    def Labels(self, Texttodisplay, WheretoPutLabels):
        self.L1 = Label(self.graphicHandle, text=Texttodisplay)
        self.L1.pack(side=WheretoPutLabels)

    def Inputs(self, WheretoPutInputs):
        self.E1 = Entry(self.graphicHandle, bd=5)
        self.E1.pack(side=WheretoPutInputs)

    def TextBox(self):
        self.filedirector = Text(self.graphicHandle)
        self.filedirector.pack()

    def PushButton(self, Command, WheretoPutPush):
        self.openfilebutton = Button(self.graphicHandle, text="Select File", fg="red", command=Command)
        self.openfilebutton.pack()


ReadinOut = logfileOpen(root)
Graphics = GraphicsStuff(root)
Graphics.Labels('Open File', 'left')
Graphics.Inputs('right')
Graphics.TextBox()
Graphics.PushButton(ReadinOut.openfileroutine, 'right')
print(ReadinOut.dataList)

# GraphicsStuff.openfilebutton.bind('<Button-1>', print("HELLO"))

# testfileclass.readlogFile()
# testfileclass.storeEvents()
# print (testfileclass.dataList)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Check if your attributes are initialised before trying to access them, hint: storeEvents()

Comment: You never call `self.storeEvents`, it should be `self.storeEvents()`

Comment: Read [python-functions](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/functions/python-functions/) and the tutorial [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on storeEvents() that was a typo on my behalf. However, it still has not solved the problem. I do agree that it seems to be an initialisation error but the error appears when I try to run the program, before any GUI has appeared. The only way to initialise those variables would be to press the GUI button to open the file explorer.

I think I am missing something very simple here but not sure what it is?